# merging two PO files usinf getText

Tags: python, windows, localization, merge, gettext

I want to create a PO file from a .properties file using msgcat and concatenate the PO files generated into a single .PO.

This operation is working properly.
My problem is while using MSGCAT it concatenates and merges the specified PO files and finds messages which are common to two or more of the specified PO files.
 It merges same translations found in different po files into one. I want to merge the same translations found in different po files to one po file with multiple of the same string. 
I don't want to remove the multiples of the same string appearing in the generated .PO file.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want to remove the multiples of the same string appearing the
>   generated .PO file.

Duplicate messages in a single po file is invalid and programs like msgmerge, msgcat & msgfmt would throw errors if you give this file as an input. Having multiple translations for a same message does not make sense, its like having same keys in a dictionary (or hashtable), how would the system know which translation to pickup.

You may want to checkout [msguniq](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msguniq-Invocation.html) to extract unique messages from an existing po file.